# How to get ROS and Anaconda to play well together?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to make sure I've done the simple and obvious things first before I post detailed questions.     I have Python 3 based software I want to bring into a ROS nodes and I use Anaconda to manage Python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307757/how-to-get-ros-and-anaconda-to-play-well-together?/) by [chrisalbertson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21344/chrisalbertson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2018-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know linking to videos is not much of an answer but from [this video](https://youtu.be/EMF20z-gT5s) you can see the necessary steps to achieve what you are asking. I'll put them here but the video is worth the check out:

1. Create a conda env with python 3 in your case.
2. Activate it.
3. `pip install -U rospkg`
4. Activate again.
5. Done

I've tested this with conda with python 2.7 and the basic pub/sub and it works.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I found this answer from a Google search, just for your information in 2021 installing ROS directly in conda (without using apt-installed ROS at all, so removing any risk of incompatibility) should be much straightforward.

In particular you can simply install ROS Noetic packages in a conda environment with the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c robostack ros-noetic-desktop
```

See the following links for more details:

- https://medium.com/robostack/cross-platform-conda-packages-for-ros-fa1974fd1de3
- https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic

---

Originally posted by [Silvio Traversaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/4782/silvio-traversaro/) with karma: 56 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-02-18**:
Instead of posting a link to a blog post could you please update your answer with a summary of it or the relevant information from it?

**Comment by [Silvio Traversaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/4782/silvio-traversaro/) on 2021-02-19**:
I should have done this, feel free to let me know if you think the new answer is ok, thanks!